# Height and width in <li> element nested in a <nav> not working

Tags: html, css

I'm writing this bit of code and it's not working the sizing (height and width) of the different classes in the nav. Can anyone please explain why? The other attributes are all running well (font-size, etc...). I'm running in chrome and firefox.

The html :

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li class="social">a</li>
        <li class="bookmarks">b</li>
        <li class="logo">brand</li>
        <li class="meta-putsches">c</li>
        <li class="login">d</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

The css :

```
nav {
  display: block;
  margin: auto; }
nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; }
nav ul li {
  display: inline;
  background-color: #000000; }
nav ul li.logo {
  width: 16em;
  height: 65px;
  font-size: 53pt;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 59pt;
  color: #f4f4f4; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `display: inline;` on the `li` element is the culprit. You can't set width or height on inline elements. You should change it to `display: inline-block;`, this will ensure that their flow is not disturbed but it enables setting the width and the height on the elements. Have a [read here at the W3 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#inline-non-replaced) to find out some more about how this works and why it works the way it does.